# cannot connect to database

Tags: database, connection, database-connection, derby

Hello while trying to connect to a derby db i'm getting

ERROR XJ040: Failed to start database 'db/mydb', see the next exception for details.
ERROR XSLAN: Database at /var/opt/myapp/db/mydb has an incompatible format with the current version of the software.  The database was created by or upgraded by version 10.5.
ij version 10.3
ij>

i wanted to ask whether i need to re-install derby or can i do a sort of trick to connect to the db

thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a 10.5 version of the database, and a 10.3 version of the IJ code. Download a 10.5 version of the IJ code from the Derby web site and use it to access the database. Here's the download site: http://db.apache.org/derby/releases/release-10.5.3.0.html